# Unable to register device after deleting installation data - Parse Push Notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I've integrated Parse Push notification in my unity iOS game. It was working fine until data of installation class were deleted accidently.
Now even after reinstallation of game, none of devices is getting registered. Please help me as I'm stucked from last few days.

My other question is, how can I update default installation class to add/edit my own custom data field ?

My game is not live. I'm using testing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this should work

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"Feed" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Please make sure that "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is calling and you are device token is not null.

You can add a column of your choice ex: user's pointer object etc...